# Lightning components in community builder

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, customer-community

I am using community templates in winter 16 org.
I want  my custom build lightning components in the community page.

I have used `implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"`
but is not displaying in page editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check the latest [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder.htm?search_text=communtity) always when working on new features

For component to be available in community use the below

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
<aura:attribute name="greeting" type="String" default="Hello" />
<aura:attribute name="subject" type="String" default="World" />

<div style="box">
  <span class="greeting">{!v.greeting}</span>, {!v.subject}!
</div>
```

> To appear in the Community Builder, a component must implement the forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes interface.